# What is the proper gradle setup for JPA Static Metamodel Generator?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use the JPA Static Metamodel generator. I found [a tutorial page](https://blog.jj-it-services.de/en/jpa-metamodel-gradle/) that explains how to set it up in Gradle. I also found [a stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36748070/9452) that says to use the same classpath.  It is:

```
classpath "gradle.plugin.at.comm_unity.gradle.plugins:jpamodelgen-plugin:1.1.1"
```

However, when I attempt to use this, I get a gradle build error:

```
Error:Could not find gradle.plugin.at.comm_unity.gradle.plugins:jpamodelgen-plugin:1.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/gradle/plugin/at/comm_unity/gradle/plugins/jpamodelgen-plugin/1.1.1/jpamodelgen-plugin-1.1.1.pom
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/gradle/plugin/at/comm_unity/gradle/plugins/jpamodelgen-plugin/1.1.1/jpamodelgen-plugin-1.1.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/gradle/plugin/at/comm_unity/gradle/plugins/jpamodelgen-plugin/1.1.1/jpamodelgen-plugin-1.1.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/gradle/plugin/at/comm_unity/gradle/plugins/jpamodelgen-plugin/1.1.1/jpamodelgen-plugin-1.1.1.jar
```

What is the problem? Is this location out-of-date? If so, what's the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the original tutorial page does have the answer, it's just commented out in the example.  The proper maven repository has to be specified.  This worked for me:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare gradle plugin libs:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven {
         url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
      }
      //... other repositories
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath "at.comm_unity.gradle.plugins.jpamodelgen:plugin:1.1.2"
   }
}
```

Apply gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: "com.github.iboyko.gradle.plugins.jpamodelgen"

jpaModelgen {
    library = "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:4.3.8.Final"
    jpaModelgenSourcesDir = "src/src/java"
}

compileJava.options.compilerArgs += ["-proc:none"]
```

The last line of the configuration should ALWAYS be present, or it will remove your original source code.

Comment: Plugin with id 'com.github.iboyko.gradle.plugins.jpamodelgen' not found.

Comment: @PiotrDajlido see: [readme](https://github.com/iboyko/gradle-plugins/blob/3d9150c567a047a01a398f9c883abf12789c6dbc/jpamodelgen-plugin/README.md)