# How to use JPA metamodel with gradle, intellij IDEA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, gradle, intellij-idea, metamodel

I am using java 8, spring boot 2.0.0, spring-data-jpa(spring-boot-starter-data-jpa), gradle, intellij. I've been trying to use JPA Metamodel, but having difficulty on finding how to configure.

Metamodels for Entity classes aren't just generated.

I guessed it would be simple, but now it seems that can be wrong. How can I use it?

Comment: This link seems helpful, maybe you can use this method http://blog.trinnovative.de/2016/02/09/generate-jpa-metamodel/

Answer (score 9):

JDK11 / Gradle 5.0 / Hibernate 5.3.7.Final

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += "${buildDir}/generated"

compileJava {
  options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated")
}

dependencies {
  annotationProcessor("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api")
  annotationProcessor("org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen")
}
```

Generated Metamodel classes will be generated at 'build/generated'

If you are using JDK8 or Hibernate 5.4+, `annotationProcessor("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api")` may unnecessary.

Comment: You saved my day! I couldn't generate anything for two days and for some reason removing the explicit version of the annotation processor made it work. I still can't figure out why, but now everything works

Comment: Me 3. After hours spent proverbially dancing around the same issue, turns out that removing the explicit version made it work.

Answer (score 1):

I did this the other day using the scalified metamodel gradle plugin (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.scalified.plugins.gradle.metamodel). I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.5, but I don't see why it wouldn't work the same with Spring Boot 2.0.0. I'm using Gradle 4.8.1 as well.

Below is an excerpt of my build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
   maven {
     url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
   }
}
dependencies {
  classpath (
      "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0",
      "gradle.plugin.com.scalified.plugins.gradle:metamodel:0.0.1");
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.scalified.plugins.gradle.metamodel"

// The plugin will default to the latest version of Hibernate if this is not specified
metamodel {
   hibernateVersion = '5.2.14.Final' // For Spring Boot 2.0.0
   hibernateVersion = '5.2.17.Final' // For Spring Boot 2.0.5
}
```

This builds the metamodal files under src/generated and they can be used in your code. I had to also change an IntelliJ setting because IntelliJ's Build Automatically excludes some Gradle tasks that could be long running.  See [Automatically run Gradle task in project build with IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717328/automatically-run-gradle-task-in-project-build-with-intellij-idea) and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175165 for more details.

This setting I changed to overcome this is: Preferences->Build/Execution/Deployment->Gradle->Runner->Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle.  An alternative would be to run the metamodelCompile gradle task manually as needed.  That would lessen the time to rebuild by a little if you aren't frequently change your entities.